# ext4 superblock checksum?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4, superblock

I'm reading the **ext4** `superblock`, but its `s_checksum` (offset 0x3FC) is always zero. Also the `s_checksum_type` (offset 0x175) field is zero as well, however according to https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#The_Super_Block
it should be 1.

Why is that?

(I'm on Ubuntu VM, which is hosted by VMWare Fusion on MacPro)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simply that the value can be either 1 or 0. There is currently only one valid checksum type (indicated by the 0x175 field). However, a value of 0 for type means that no checksum is used. This appears to be the default for at least Debian-based distros. Checksumming can be enabled as described in the OP linked document:

```
tune2fs -O metadata_csum /dev/path/to/disk
```